# Laravel-5.4 - store the image path in database for all users who registers

Tags: php, database, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel-5.4 make:auth. Added one extra field in user table -> profile picture in views\auth\register.blade.php. I want to do the following:
1. How to store the image path in database for all users who registers.

Have tried defining store function in existing app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php. It doesn't even get into store function. Where and how to write the store function , so that the controller executes it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're handling image uploading with JS and `image_path` field in the form already has path to the image, then just modify `create()` method in `Auth/RegisterController.php` controller:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'image_path' => $data['image_path'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: no, I am just choosing an image and uploading it, which inturn stores a temporary path in database like  C:\xampp\tmp\php469E.tmp. I want to store the image in public folder and store the image path.I wrote store function in Auth/RegisterController.php,it doesn't work.I am learning laravel for my new project.So any suggestions on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get to your method, just check if your form matches it properly. E.g.:

```
<form method="POST" action="route('register.user)">
 ...
</form>
```

Route & controller:

```
Route::post('/users/register', [
'uses' => 'UserController@register',
'as' => 'register.user'
]);

public function register(Request $request){
    if ($file = $request->file('photo_id')) {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images', $name);
        $photo = Photo::create(['file' => $name]);
    }
    ...other methods/logic...
}
```

Comment: used your option and I am able to see my function is getting called. My need is want to write a store function in their existing `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterControl‌​ler.php`. because there is where new user registration details are getting validated. The existing routes  `Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('regis‌​ter');    Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register'); ` only takes this in action.